# image height is relative to file size instead of parent div (full page horizontal scroll gallery)

Tags: html, css, image

I'm pretty new to html and css and stumbled over following:

i want to create a horizontal image gallery webpage. i've choosen a table layout as it expands beyond viewport. All images shall have the same height (80% of the viewports height (.gallery-container), resize in width to achieve the original aspect ratio and the table cells should expand in width to place all pictures nicely next to each other, way beyond the viewport, to achieve a horizontal-scroll webpage.

the only way i found to resize the image relative to its parent, is to set its position property to absolute, but this causes the parent div not to expand in width, so i ended up with another problem (the pictures laying over each other).

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>BOSS</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
        <div class="gallery-container"><table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="image-container"><img src="images/wind1.jpg" class="gallery-image"></div></td>
                        <td><div class="image-container"><img src="images/wind2.jpg" class="gallery-image"></div></td>
                        <td><div class="image-container"><img src="images/wind3.jpg" class="gallery-image"></div></td>
                        <td><div class="image-container"><img src="images/wind4.jpg" class="gallery-image"></div></td>
                        <td><div class="image-container"><img src="images/wind5.jpg" class="gallery-image"></div></td>
                    </tr></table></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}

html, body, div, table, td, tr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.gallery-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    height: 80%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border:0;
}

.image-container {
    margin: 0 2rem 0;
}

.gallery-image {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: inherit;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rewjrext/1/

i've been googling this for hours now and really would like to understand why the image height is relative to its file size instead of the parent div or at least how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Tables are for data. Tables are for data. Tables are for data.

Comment: ignore isherwood - Nothing wrong with tables for simple layouts. Afterall an image can also be data. Perhaps you are displaying profile pictures of a User record.  If you have to nest a bunch of tables to get the desired result then use DIVs.

Comment: @isherwood i know that using tables for layout is sooooooooooo 90's ;) but as they're recommended for horizontal-scroll webpages [link](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/) and its an artists webpage, the gallery for his photography.... but anyway, that wasn't my question :)

Comment: That article is from 2008. That's about 3 web-lifetimes ago. Tables are for data. Using them for other purposes is plain wrong, and it's trivial to do horizontal scroll by modern means. Ask anyone who is visually impaired what they think of table layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why the height property of the image was relative in my case:

there is a w3c specification, which says, that the height of an image in percentage is depended on referring on a px value.

in my case, as the picture shall always be 80% of the viewport, i used the unit vh the specify the height of the image

```
.gallery-image
height: 80vh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add width: 100% to `.gallery-image` **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3a8fztww/1/)**

```
.gallery-image {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

One thing would is get rid of is (just a suggestion) `height: 80%;` on `.gallery-container`. Let the turkey fly!

**EDIT:**
Changed `width` to `max-width` as per @isherwood suggestion.

Comment: `max-width` may be better, depending on whether the images are always large enough.

Comment: Okay, all images are scaled now, but way to much. my goal is to set the height of all images equal to the height of .gallery-container. That's why I set it's height to 80%

Comment: @maxp Add line line-height: 0; to html, body, div, table, td, tr{}.  https://jsfiddle.net/rewjrext/2/

Comment: @dowomenfart nothing changed.. and getting rid of the 100% height In The html, body, div...{}  causes the top positioning of Gallery-Container  not to work. My goal is a vertical aligned gallery, all images scaled at 80% of the viewport's height. I would really appreciate a solution for that. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: What i just got: your Solution creates a Gallery that Always fits The viewport, but i want to have a horizontal scrollbar and The image Gallery expanding horizontally way beyond The viewport

Comment: i updated my entry, so the main point should be clear now. sorry for that